# How can I specify which php.ini file to use in my nginx conf file?

Tags: nginx, php5, php.ini

I'm running 2 PHP sites on the same server. I would like to use 2 different php.ini files for them. I've googled this issue with [no luck](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=nginx%20specify%20php.ini%20file&es_th=1). Here is what my php location looks like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because you don't do that - you configure php-fpm however you want (mutiple instances if desired) and point at whichever one you want to use.

Comment: @AD7six - I see. Any good references on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @AD7six, I was going about it the wrong way. This is how I solved the issue for anyone else who isn't as familiar with multiple php setups.

Copy the default pool to create our new pool. (You can name the pool whatever you want, in this example I am using `www2`):

```
sudo cp /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www2.conf
sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www2.conf
```

Change the pool name:

```
[www] => [www2]
```

Change the listening socket:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock => /var/run/php5-fpm2.sock
```

Unfortunately, specifying php.ini files based on pool is impossible. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20930969/1408717)) But as the answer there states, you can overwrite individual php.ini values. It's not great but as far as I can tell, there's no other way of doing it.

A note for overwriting the php.ini values: There are 4 ways of doing this, *php_value*, *php_flag*, *php_admin_value*, and *php_admin_flag*. Use the `_flag` commands when setting booleans. Use the `_value` commands for anything else. The `_admin` versions make it so those values/flags cannot be overwritten.

Finally, change your nginx.conf to use the new pool:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock => unix:/var/run/php5-fpm2.sock
```